# the video file does not show up in the $_FILES array

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, file-upload, mp4

I'm trying to get my website to upload video's and pictures. As I have made more websites that upload pictures there is no problem on that front, but when i try to upload a video for some reason it can't be found in the `$_FILES` array that contains an uploaded image.

What i have is:

```
<form method="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
    <table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Selecteer een bestand:*
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="file" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input style="font-size: 10pt; cursor: hand;" type="submit" name="insturen" value="Insturen">
                <input style="font-size: 10pt; cursor: hand;" type="submit" name="klaar" value="Klaar met Uploaden">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Uploading images is no problem at all, but when i put a mp4 in there it will not even show up at all! Any idea what's going wrong?

Any help is appriciated!

**EDIT**
I forgot to add this:

I have already googled and found stuff about the php.ini file containing max sizes for uploads. these are all set to 200M:

```
max_execution_time = 1000
max_input_time = 1000
memory_limit = 256M
upload_max_filesize = 200M
post_max_size = 200M
```

**EDIT 2**
After some testing it appears that really small video files do work (192KB) but somewhat bigger doesnt show anyting in the $_FILES array (11MB) but really big files (80MB) gives an error: `The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length.`. The problem is that i have set the `maxAllowedContentLength` to 500000000. So that shouldn't happen?!

Comment: The issue is probably the file size limit in your `php.ini` file.

Comment: The max file size is set to 200M

Comment: You should also set `maxRequestLength` to something longer to allow the HTTP request in whole to be large enough to support the uploaded file.

Comment: Also set that one to 200MB, still doesnt work =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a maximum upload file size set in `php.ini`, so the problem is likely related to the size of your file. By default it's 2MB for files / 8MB total POST size. Look for the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` directives in php.ini and change them to a more appropriate size.

Comment: The max file size is set to 200M

Comment: What's the `post_max_size` set to?

Comment: also 200M (see question for more settings)

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of the video files? You might have to set the following in your .htaccess

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
```

or in your php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize 10M
post_max_size 10M
```

Just change the 10M to any size you want.

Comment: The max file size is set to 200M